# How do I configure Laravel for Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got the instance going and everything but my config doesn't work and I don't what to try to make it work.

All I get are 503 errors and no explanation.

Production mode config

```
return array(
    'url' => 'http://patientdueling.com',
     'asset_url' => '',
    'profiler' => false,
    'ssl' => false,
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I switched from a dedicated server I could control to Elastic Beanstalk server and RDS with AWS for some reason my environment of production vs development was no longer being detected.

I copied my production config into laravel's default config and it worked!

My error:

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock)' in /var/www/html/laravel/database/connectors/mysql.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/laravel/laravel.php(42): Laravel\Error::native(2, 'PDO::__construc...', '/var/www/html/l...', 33)
#1 [internal function]: Laravel\{closure}(2, 'PDO::__construc...', '/var/www/html/l...', 33, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/laravel/database/connectors/mysql.php(33): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/laravel/database.php(66): Laravel\Database\Connectors\MySQL->connect(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/laravel/database.php(52): Laravel\Database::connect(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/laravel/database/eloquent/query.php(255): Laravel\Database::connection(NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/laravel/database/eloquent/query.php(245): Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Query->connection()
#7 /var/www/html/laravel/database/eloquent/query.php(50): Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Query->table()
#8 /var/www/html/laravel/database/eloquent/model.php(473): Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Query->__construct(Object(System))
#9 /var/www/html/laravel/database/eloquent/model.php(789): Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Model->query()
#10 [internal function]: Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('where_real_syst...', Array)
#11 [internal function]: System->where_real_system_id(0)
#12 /var/www/html/laravel/database/eloquent/model.php(804): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/html/application/controllers/system.php(86): Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic('where_real_syst...', Array)
#14 /var/www/html/application/controllers/system.php(86): System::where_real_system_id(0)
#15 [internal function]: System_Controller->get_list()
#16 /var/www/html/laravel/routing/controller.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 /var/www/html/laravel/routing/controller.php(285): Laravel\Routing\Controller->response('list', Array)
#18 /var/www/html/laravel/routing/controller.php(165): Laravel\Routing\Controller->execute('list', Array)
#19 /var/www/html/laravel/routing/route.php(153): Laravel\Routing\Controller::call('system@list', Array)
#20 /var/www/html/laravel/routing/route.php(124): Laravel\Routing\Route->response()
#21 /var/www/html/laravel/laravel.php(167): Laravel\Routing\Route->call()
#22 /var/www/html/public/index.php(34): require('/var/www/html/l...')
#23 {main}
```

Comment: Hello Michael, I am from the future, you just saved me from this problem again. Thank you.  P.S. we all wear jump suits now.